# Python Multiprocessing: Running each iteration of multiple for loops in parallel

Tags: python, loops, process, multiprocessing

I have two loops in python. Here is some pseudo code. I would like to run both those functions and each iteration of each of those functions at the same time. So in this example, there would be 8 processes going on at once. I know you can use "Process", but I just don't know how to incorporate an iterable. Please let me know, thanks!

```
import...

def example1(iteration):
    print('stuff')

def example2(iteration):
    print('stuff')

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    freeze_support()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    iteration = [1,2,3,4]
    pool.map(example1,iteration)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they don't need to be kicked off at exactly the same time I think [`map_async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map_async) is what you want.

In the example bellow we can print the result from `example2` before `example1` has finished even though `example1` was kicked off first.

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def example1(iteration):
    time.sleep(1)
    return 1

def example2(iteration):
    return 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    iteration = [1,2,3,4]
    result1 = pool.map_async(example1, iteration)
    result2 = pool.map_async(example2, iteration)
    print(result2.get())
    print(result1.get())
```